# How to disable a DisclosureGroup?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

SwiftUI allows to disable a `NavigationLink`. This fades its color it and prevents user from tapping it.

```
List {
    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination")) {
        Text("Some link")
    }.disabled(true)
}
```

This behavior is not the same with `DisclosureGroup`. **Only the arrow is faded and the text is still tappable.**

```
List {
    DisclosureGroup("Some group") {
        Text("Some content")
    }.disabled(true)
}
```

Is this a bug or is this the desired behavior? If so, is it possible to completely disable a `DisclosureGroup`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour, for me both the text and the arrow are faded and not tappable.

Comment: In your example, both the text and the arrow are disabled and their color faded. None is tappable.

Comment: I edited both examples to reproduce the situation. As soon as `DisclosureGroup` is in a `List`, `disabled(true)` no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can serve as a workaround, setting `.isExpanded` to false always:

```
        List {
            DisclosureGroup("Some group", isExpanded: .constant(false)) {
                Text("Some content")
            }
            .disabled(true)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this will do the trick. Hopefully this `disabled` bug will be fixed in SwiftUI 4!